# Where can i set the duration for CarouFredSel javascript in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, duration, caroufredsel

Does anyone knows where you can set the duration for CarouFredSel javascript in wordpress?

Source: http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel

Answer (score 1):

Duration is listed in the documentation under "Hook up the carousel", is that what you meant?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// Using default configuration
$('#carousel').carouFredSel();
// Using custom configuration
$('#carousel').carouFredSel({
    items                : 2,
    direction            : "up",
    scroll : {
        items            : 1,
        easing            : "elastic",
        duration        : 1000,
        pauseOnHover    : true
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Actually i'm not a programmer. I'm just a little bit into programming. I want to change the duration of this carousel somewhere in a configuration file in wordpress.
Your code seems clear to me, but i don't know here to find that piece of code. Could you tell me where to look in wordpress?

Comment: Oh I see. Ok, well if you've manged to get the carousel set up properly then all you need to do is paste the above script into your header.php between the <head> tags and it should override the carousels default controls.

Comment: Ok, i have tried this and copied the script into the header. But nothing has changed the carousel slides in any way. Even after changing the parameters in your script. 
Maybe i need to find an other plugin for testimonial slides..

Can i send you a personal message to have a look to the wordpress site?